# Working with compressed files

Tags: java, compression, zip

I would like to know the best way to work with packed files in java. I know I can use ZIP but I'm not interested in compression.. so is ZIP the fastest way?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "pack?" That sounds like "compression" to me...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: by "pack" i mean something like tar.. just file kept together. Now, I know I can use tar for my purposes, just want to know if one is significant faster than the other (assuming lot of files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip format has a "stored" compression level which actually means *no compression* - it just packs files. It is therefore fast. At the same time, zip is a very popular format, and one can read it on almost any system.

Answer (score 0):

check this link
[Class ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)

**setLevel**

```
public void setLevel(int level)
```

Sets the compression level for subsequent entries which are DEFLATED.
The default setting is DEFAULT_COMPRESSION.
Parameters:
level - the compression level (0-9)
Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - if the compression level is invalid